Why did Stack Overflow sign-ups spike in the past two weeks?
While exploring some SEDE queries, a recent peak of user signups stood out:

If this query is correct, this is far above baseline sign-up activity observed over the past years. Moreover, last week saw a huge spike in last access date activity:

To me, this seems way over baseline. What is going on here?
Inspecting phrases
For anyone wanting to inspect the phrase distribution of these accounts, check out this query I wrote.
Additional charts
Below charts put the recent spike in perspective:

Based on changing the date range to 2008 and minimum post count to 1 in this query originally posted by Starball, these recent signups have not lead to a significant increase in asking/answering activity (a slight hike in questions asked). If this was an automated effort, for what purpose might these accounts have been created? And if not, where have all these new users come from?


as a pessimist...  spammer wave?

If so, looking at the total weekly signups since 2008 there hasn't been anything of this scale.

Spam accounts are very often months to years old, with the first post being spam. Fortunately for us, age makes no difference to the effectiveness of the system that catches them out.

I am just wondering where the 750.000 users signed up in the past month came from, even if they are bots. I also added some additional charts to put this sign-up spike into context.

Might have been due to the A-B test testing out one-tap Google login on SO. Currently, that's configured to automatically sign someone in, which I think explains the spike. That also has some unintended side effects, such as one's profile being instantly recreated after they delete it themselves.

For reference to Sonic's comment: Being logged in with a Google account automatically creates Stack account

I noticed a similar out burst of account creation on Stack Apps in May 2023. Here is a query that gives insight in accounts that are created close together: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1837390?year=2024-04-18&seconds=10

on the bright side, all these people will start seeing meta stuff in the community bulletin, which is nice :P

In the mean time celebrations at Stack Exchange HQ for how the KPI "new users" is doing ...

@gparyani I believe that's the case indeed, IMO worth an answer. Worst case, if it's not, staff can always come and post the actual reason, and delete your own.

Still curious that there is an even bigger spike last week though. Something must be driving more people to the site, causing them to get automatically logged in.

It's funny that the question is asked by an account that's less that's two weeks old.

@yivi yes, I got caught by the new streamlined sign-up process..

tbf, if you're going to look at signups, and ask questions on meta about data anomalies? You're clearly in the right place, 2 week old account, or 2 year old account. Clearly OP fits right in :D

@rene Maybe now they can stop with the AI stuff and work on Q&A now that we have more new users again...

@rene I'll bet the burst of account creation on Stack Apps in May 2023 are the loan sharks.

@gparyani I wonder, though, why these re-registered accounts would warrant a new accountId on a live production server? It introduces a heavy skew in the distribution of ids.

There is an uptick in asking for the last 2-3 data points (although that can also be the really bad questions that get removed later on).

@gparyani Phillippe just posted an update on the Stack Exchange meta regarding the site-wide update. As a newly minted user, just wondering why this was moved and also, why reputation from the migrated post isn't transferred to the current account?

@DennisLeeftink votes on Meta Stack Exchange affect reputation, votes on other Meta sites like Meta Stack Overflow do not and the reputation shown is the reputation you have on the main site (with some caching involved so there would be some delay in syncing). This was probably moved here because it was specifically about [so].

@AbdulAzizBarkat I understand. We have since come to know that it is a site wide update that is likely causing the spike, not only on Stack Overflow. Should this be migrated once more? The plots can be easily adjusted to account for all networks.

concerning the migration to MSO, I assumed the new signin thing affected all SE sites... did I assume wrong? @gparyani

@DennisLeeftink Hmm, technically it is possible to reject the migration here (either by closing this post or maybe a moderator would be able to reject directly) which would cause it to go back. I don't know whether the back and forth would be worth it though. If you feel that this should be on MSE feel free to flag for a moderator.

If that's so, then I'd edit this to feature charts from across the network (examples from different sites) as well as change the title to no longer specifically reference Stack Overflow, then flag for a moderator here to close this question, which will return it back to Meta Stack Exchange.

@gparyani No spikyness detected on some of the larger Exchanges, so it currently seems localised to SO. Re: this comment I do think it warrants some 'site-wide' reflection, as the uptick in accountIds will affect current and future SEDE queries. Are existing users assigned a new id when re-registering for one-tap sign-on? Can these ids be linked back to previous post histories? If we are dealing with a superset of existing ids mixed in with new ones, site wide statistics can be heavily impacted if not properly filtered.

Do the stats also count disabled accounts? Because you seem to plot the age of (active) accounts, and it is not that strange, that people that are new, also get rid of the account quite soon.

Automatic Account Creation just by being logged in into my google account must be the worst idea I have ever seen.

Might this have something to do with the 1-Rep voting experiment? The last weeks peak might be a bit late to be acounted to that experiment, but maybe there are some side effects?

@Felix that experiment didn't happen

Could it simply be ML training scrapers looking to ingest the entire SO section of the interwebs?

@ed2 you don't need an account to view/scrape SO content. much less hundreds or thousands of accounts. plus, SO data is already freely available via data dumps.

Related:  https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/402229/

@Daviid That (mostly) didn't happen! It's only "automatic" for users who previously logged in with Google and later deleted their Stack Exchange account. In that case, yes, it's re-creating the account and that's bad. But for the vast majority of users, that's not the case, and they're creating accounts using one-click Google login, which I also don't love but isn't in the same category of misbehaviour (and security catastrophe!) as creating accounts unprompted would be.
